# react native ':app:packageRelease' always failed because it's finding my old keystore that I deleted

Tags: android, react-native, keystore

I build a release apk with a keystore that i generated, but for some reason, i deleted my old keystore and generated a new one with a new name and password, but the problem is, every time I'm building my new release apk with my new keystore, it always failed with an error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> /path/to/my/react-native/project/android/app/my-old-keystore.keystore (No such file or directory)
```

My gradle.properties

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-new-keystore.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=mykeyalias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=123456
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=123456
```

why the ':app:packageRelease' always finding my old keystore, and how can I make him ignore my `my-old-keystore.keystore` and focus only on `my-new-keystore.keystore` so I can generate a release apk?

Comment: what keystore does your gradle.properties under android folder indicate?

Comment: @kenmistry done editing sir, i added my gradle.properties